# Localhost refused to connect wamp windows 10

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, localhost, wamp

I moved the live wordpress site from server to localhost.
But it has same error "localhost refused to connect"
My other wordpress site in the localhost are working only moved site not working.
I configured wp-config.php and changed URL's but it all same.
What should i do ?

[moved wordpress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40oPc.png)

[working wordpress site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdEsl.png)

Comment: Have you enabled `https` ?

Comment: No, i will try thank you for your advice

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Otherwise run127.0.0.1/wordperss

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you transferred the site and database correctly, I doubt you are running your local WAMP instance with an SSL certificate.

Try visiting `http://localhost/gobishop/en`, without the https.